# portable way of checking parameters against printf format in compile time, C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a log function `my_log(const char* my_fmt, ...)` doing customized logging. I would like `my_log` to follow the C `printf` convention. To save me troubles, I'd like to warn users of any warning and error `printf()` would give. The printf feature I need is `-Wformat` warning. And errors of course.

**Question:** How can I achieve this without any runtime overhead? (not using compiler specific feature).

In GCC, I can use `__attribute__((format()))`.

```
void __attribute__((format(printf,1,2))) my_log(const char* fmt, ...){ }
```

For now, I need to compile on Intel C++ compiler (ICC) and GCC. If I could achieve the attribute checking in ICC, that would be good. If there were a pure C++ language trick to do such checking at compile-time, that would be awesome.

Comment: There isn't a portable way to do this; you can probably use some static code analyzers to help with this; however.

Comment: Choose a language. In C++, you might be able to cobble together a `constexpr` variadic template to check the types match, but why not do something more type-safe in the first place? In C, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: An idea for consideration: When compiling under "DEBUG", define `my_log(x)` to `my_log_debug(sprintf(some_global_big_buffer, x))` or something like this to use `sprintf` to get the parameter checking albeit not exact `my_log()` functionality.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks. I choose C++. I am not sure what does "type-safe" do you mean? I tried to preserve the current interface of logging, otherwise, every logline would require rewrite. Besides, the user likes to log in the feeling of "printf" style. I would very much like to know the 'type-safe' way.

Comment: @chux Thanks. looks like a decent workaround. Tell user to fix any error/warning in debug build. Then they can move forward to release build.

Comment: If you are able to use C++11, see the example code at http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates

Comment: @chux: Good thinking. With an unevaluated context, e.g. `sizeof(printf(...))` you should be able to get the warning with needing a "debug" build.

Comment: Why bother? If you're compiling the code on both platforms you'll get warnings anyway - presumably your normal procedure will be to build on all platforms before committing to trunk, let alone releasing.  (Obligatory quip - better yet, use type-safe streams.)

Comment: What features of `printf` formatting are you using.  As an example, are you using positional arguments?  There are [C++11 libraries](https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat) that do high-performance type-checked `printf` formatting that you may want to consider.

Comment: You're asking for pure C solution, but you put C++ and C++11 tags. So, what language?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am sorry. I have corrected the post description. If we can do in C, we can do in C++. So I will go for C++.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks a lot. I think -Wformat is what I want. my_log("Hello %s %d %i %p %x ...", p1, p2, ...). Have already updated the post description.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk - I've hated IOStreams forever. One more arrow in quiver.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to do this. Even for the `printf` family the language lets the compiler assume you know what you're doing and compile what you've written although g++ does provide a helpful warning if you enable it.

Since your project is C++ why not use a C++ idiom and use `boost::format` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) or IO streams? Then you get type safety and don't need to even worry about validating the input.

Comment: Thanks. Mark. I do not want to do real logging (string manipulating etc) in my_log(), since it is very slow. I just want the compiler to validate parameters on each occurrence of my_log(), since the format string and parameter types are know at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers said, there is no portable/standard way to achieve what the question asks for. However, the Intel C/C++ compilers (icc and icpc) are **100% compatible** with GNU function attributes. See [Intel XE13](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-F4210147-81E1-4EF4-854D-885BD5EC8CA6.htm). icpc does give the -Wformat warnings when I declare `__attribute__((format())).`

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to do it.

You can use variadic templates to check arguments at runtime, but it will slow down the `my_log()`.

Also, you can try following solution, but then `my_log()` will not follow the `printf` convention.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <initializer_list>
#include <sstream>

class UC
{
    static std::stringstream ss;
    std::string str;
    friend const char *Str(std::initializer_list<UC> data);
public:
    template <class T> UC(T param) : str((ss.str(""), ss << param, ss.str())) {}
};
std::stringstream UC::ss;

void my_log(std::initializer_list<UC> data)
{
    std::string in_str;
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
        ret += it->str;

    std::cout << in_str.c_str() << '\n'; // Or whatever you want to do with your string.
}


int main()
{
    my_log({"Hello", '!', 11});
}
```